# Vbs to run an uninstaller silently or click confirm?

Tags: command, uninstallation, silent

So I have a utility on about 250 computers that is now obsolete. The remote management program I use will not easily let me remove it via the gui.  I am no programmer.  Not by a long shot.  I need a script to run via the remote command prompt to remove the file.  I can easily delete the folder it is in but this will leave the registry entry's and thus still list it as installed.  I would love to run it 100% silent but if not I at least need the script to confirm when the Uninstall confirm box pops up.  I have searched and tried copy and paste with some success.  Thanks for any helpful constructive criticism or entire scripts!  Haha

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here.  Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Thanks!  I will tomorrow when I am at pc.